# mysql - Get tables with a specified number at the end of the name

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all tables that have a specified number at the end of the name (the number is the current year - 6 months concat with current month - 6 months).

I tried this but it fails since tb is not a column

```
SELECT 
 table_name AS tb
FROM 
 information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema = DATABASE()
AND tb LIKE "something_%"
AND (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH,'%Y%m')) < RIGHT(tb, 6)
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias in the WHERE clause. And the `LIKE` doesn't support and `AND` like you seem to wish. You have to build your string with `CONCAT()`

```
SELECT 
 table_name AS tb
FROM 
 information_schema.tables
WHERE 
 table_schema = DATABASE()
AND table_name LIKE CONCAT('something', (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH,'%Y%m')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, this smells like a bad table design. If your information has to be encoded in the table name you could just as well put it in columns in the table. The problem would then not occur.

And secondly, your SELECT statement is missing a FROM - but the entire second SELECT is not gonna work like that... But I don't really know how to help there. Look at my first point ;-)